# Java .jar file, .txt file not changing

Tags: jar

I have a java program that writes text to a .txt file. I want to make a jar file so I can run the program without having to load up the eclipse environment. I have used the eclipse function to create a runnable jar file.

I double click this so that the program executes. Then when I browse to the text file in windows explorer its always empty. Why is this ?

When I run the program in the eclipse IDE and browse for the file it shows the text correctly.

Thanks All.

Comment: Is there any output? What does the code look like?

Comment: The code is just normal code to write to a text file. Ive pasted it below if it helps.

Comment: public void writefms(Integer [] a, Integer [] b) throws IOException{
 
 PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("H:\\SSI Files\\SSI Prog - Copy - Copy\\Program\\Errors Reported.txt"));
 p.write("SIGNIFICANT DATALINK ERRORS ON" + "\n" );
 p.println();
 
 
   s = ("TFM" + " " + e );//"  " + a[e]);
   p.write(s + "\n");
   p.println();
  }
 }
 
 for(int e = 0; e<b.length; e++){
  
  }
 }
 
 if(s.equals("w")){
  p.write("No TFM with datalink errors greater then 100");
  }
 
 p.close();
}
}

Comment: When i browse in windows for the  H:\\SSI Files\\SSI Prog - Copy - Copy\\Program\\Errors Reported.txt" file. Its just blank.

Comment: Try running the program like this from the command line: `java -jar program.jar`. Does it have any output?